# Advanced Wordpress SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

after 4 hours I am not able to find solution, how to correctly write the SQL query to echo data from two tables.

I have two tables and I need to "JOIN" theirs data.

First table is "wp_users" and the second is "wp_usermeta".

From "wp_users" all I need is "user_email" (So it would be SELECT user_email FROM wp_users).

But I need to join the other table called "wp_usermeta" where I need a lot of stuff like "first_name", "last_name", "phone_number", "schoolid", "schoolname" etc.

And HERE COMES TO PROBLEM :-)

In wp_usermeta I need to read data from two columns - "meta_key" and "meta_value". Column "meta_key" stores the name of the variable (for example "schoolid" and column "meta_value" stores the value of the meta_key (for example "XXXXXXXX").

I have this code:

```
  <table>
    <tr><th>Email Address</th><th>First Name</th></tr>
  <?php
   $teacher_table = "SELECT wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
  FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
     WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'";


   $results_table_main = $wpdb->get_results($teacher_table);

      foreach ($results_table_main as $value){
     echo '<tr><td>'.$value->user_email .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$value->meta_value .'</td>';
     } ?>
    </table>
```

This works, but I have no idea how to modify it to get more meta_keys with their meta_values.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want can be done with one query, but it could get messy.  You may want to consider making it multiple queries.  But here's what it looks like with a single query:

```
SELECT wp_users.user_email,
       usermeta_firstname.meta_value AS first_name,
       usermeta_lastname.meta_value AS last_name
  FROM wp_users
         INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_firstname
                 ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_firstname.user_id
                AND usermeta_firstname.meta_key = 'first_name'
         INNER JOIN wp_usermeta AS usermeta_lastname
                 ON wp_users.ID = usermeta_lastname.user_id
                AND usermeta_lastname.meta_key = 'last_name'
```

Then just keep rejoining the wp_usermeta table for each field needed.  Note that if you're going to use `INNER JOIN` then all of the values must exist.  If you want to account for potentially missing values, use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Both of the solution will not work... I have to somehow find the way to create query, which takes a meta_value according to defined meta_key -> and this is from only one table. So lets say, I need schoolid -> than I have to select wp_usermeta -> user_metakey("schoolid") and from this defined metakey I need its meta_value. It soo complicated. Anyway, thanks for advices :-)

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the question.  I re-wrote my answer, so that should help.

Comment: Nice!  Now how do I take those results and INSERT them into a new table called "compiled_user_data"?

Answer (score 1):

I feel I'm missing something. But you can just remove the WHERE clause from your sql query to get all meta values.

Or select the values you want with ORs.

```
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'
OR wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'fist_name'
/*...*/
```

Edit:

In both cases you need to SELECT meta_key as well, so you know what the value is. Then I would use PHP to transform the result to your needs.

Comment: I made this code:         <table>
            <tr><th>Email Address</th><th>Nick Name</th><th>First Name</th></tr>
        <?php
$teacher_table = "SELECT wp_users.user_email, wp_usermeta.meta_value 
FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'nickname'
OR wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name'
";
 
 
 $results_table_main = $wpdb->get_results($teacher_table);

foreach ($results_table_main as $value){
   echo '<tr><td>'.$value->user_email .'</td>';
   echo '<td>'.$value->meta_value .'</td>';
} ?>
        </table> //no work

Comment: What do you mean by no work? Also I took first_name from your question. I don't know if it might be firstname or `First Name` or ....Please make sure that you use the right meta key.

Comment: It works! A bit in a different way than I want to, but it works :-) Thank you.